# How to add hit/click event to AmCharts 4 Range? (ValueAxisDataItem)

Tags: events, range, click, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm trying to add click events to a range on a graph very similar to this

https://codepen.io/ChazUK/pen/VwjqWNJ?editable=true

```
for (let grading of data.gradingData) {
    var range = axis2.axisRanges.create();
    range.axisFill.fill = am4core.color(grading.color);
    range.axisFill.fillOpacity = 0.8;
    range.axisFill.zIndex = -1;
    range.value = grading.lowScore > chartMin ? grading.lowScore : chartMin;
    range.endValue = grading.highScore < chartMax ? grading.highScore : chartMax;
    range.grid.strokeOpacity = 0;
    range.stroke = am4core.color(grading.color).lighten(-0.1);
    range.label.inside = true;
    range.label.text = grading.title.toUpperCase();
    range.label.inside = true;
    range.label.location = 0.5;
    range.label.inside = true;
    range.label.radius = am4core.percent(10);
    range.label.paddingBottom = -5; // ~half font size
    range.label.fontSize = "0.9em";
}
```

The idea is that a user can click on a range and change the value of the hand to point to it.

I've seen that axis labels are clickable, but can't find any events on ranges or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable interactions on the range's `axisFill` object as it is disabled by default. Once you do that, you can listen to the `hit` event on it:

```
range.axisFill.interactionsEnabled = true; //required so that the hit event will trigger
range.axisFill.events.on('hit', function(ev) {
  // ...
});
```